# Is there a possibility to colorize the pdf bookmarks in the sidebar of acrobat reader

Tags: hyperref, color, bookmarks

I want to colorize my bookmarks in this way. Is there any chance to do this with the `hyperref` package? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible, using `bookmark` package

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the `\bookmark` command and its `color=` option. However, `hyperref` adds automatically bookmarks unless the `tocdepth` is smaller than `-1`, so using `\bookmark` would double the entries.

Setting `tocdepth` to `-2` temporarily`will disable this, use`\bookmark`then with a destination and use the the relevant sectioning command then (or whatever should be bookmarked),after that set the`tocdepth` to another value again to provided the automatically generated bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}
\bookmark[level=0,dest=chap:here,color=blue]{A chapter}

\chapter{A chapter}\hypertarget{chap:here}{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\section{Another level}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. how can i change the color of a specific bookmark (e.g. make all chapters blue or only bibliography red)?

Comment: @Jaska: Use `color=red` for example and the `bookmarkdefinestyle` command -- please look into the `bookmark` manual.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting this in your preamble works fine:

```
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarkdefinestyle{TheStyleOfTheBookmark0}{color=blue} % Farbe Bookmark Chapter
\bookmarkdefinestyle{TheStyleOfTheBookmark1}{color=green} % Farbe Bookmark Section
\bookmarkdefinestyle{TheStyleOfTheBookmark2}{color=red} % Farbe Bookmark Subsection
\bookmarkdefinestyle{TheStyleOfTheBookmark3}{color=black} % Farbe Bookmark Subsubsection
\bookmarksetup{open,addtohook=\bookmarksetup{style=TheStyleOfTheBookmark\bookmarkget{level}}}
```

Comment: Perhaps a hint to the manual as I gave you in my answer would be useful.